# Omit hanging indent in bibtex

Tags: bibliographies, formatting, indentation, bold

I use `\bibliographystyle{alpha}` with `bibtex` (not `biblatex`). The document class is `scrreprt`. The output looks like

```
[Abc07] Example Abc. The title and all other stuff.
        dddd. 2007.
[Bcd08] Ex Bcd. The title, the journal and all other stuff.
        cccc. 2008.
```

But I want something like

```
[Abc07] Example Abc. The title and all other stuff.
dddd. 2007.

[Bcd08] Ex Bcd. The title, the journal and all other stuff.
cccc. 2008.
```

where the labels `[Abc07]` and `[Bcd08]` should be **bold**. So I don't want the hanging indent. But with a small vertical space between the entries.

Can someone help me?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The `thebibliography` environment is a `list` environment and you should change the parameters for it. Basically, instead of setting the `\leftmargin` we set the `\itemindent` to contain the label and the separation, while keeping the `\leftmargin` to zero.

```
\begin{filecontents*}{\jobname.bib}
@article{A,
 author={Author, A.},
 title={The title of this article that should be long enough to wrap},
 journal={Journal of Irreproducible Results},
 year={2042},
}
@article{B,
 author={Buthor, B.},
 title={The title of this article that should be long enough to wrap},
 journal={Journal of Irreproducible Results},
 year={2042},
}
\end{filecontents*}

\documentclass{scrreprt}

%%% Code to add to your document
\usepackage{etoolbox}
\patchcmd{\thebibliography}
  {\advance\leftmargin\labelsep}
  {\leftmargin=0pt\itemindent=\labelwidth\advance\itemindent\labelsep}
  {}{}
%%% end of code to add    

\begin{document}
\nocite{*}
\bibliographystyle{alpha}
\bibliography{\jobname}
\end{document}
```

The example uses a `filecontents*` environment, but all you need is the marked code.

[image]

If you want that the labels are rendered in boldface, with a normal space after them, the code to add is

```
\patchcmd{\thebibliography}
  {\advance\leftmargin\labelsep}
  {\leftmargin=0pt\labelwidth=0pt\labelsep=0pt}
  {}{}
\makeatletter
\renewcommand{\@biblabel}[1]{[\textbf{#1}]~}
\makeatother
```

Here's a picture:

[image]

Comment: Thanks. 2 more questions to your solution: 1) Is there a way to get the labels ([Aut42], ...) in boldface? 2) At the moment if there are for example labels [RT09] and [Hum96] (of different width) there is a large space between the label and the text. Is there a way that the text start directly after the label? Something like `[Aut42]~A.~Author`.

Comment: @Ivo I've added the code; it's better to act on `\@bibitem` than on `\@lbibitem`.